# Intersect multiple binary rasters based on certain criteria in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have multiple binary raster image (0.1). For example if I have n images, how can I extract the pixels that has the value of 1 and frequently occurred " the same pixels" in 70% of the n images (for example if I have 10 images, I need to extract the pixels that has the value of 1 in and frequently exist in at least 7 images.

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform raster algebra to produce a 4-bit raster with the sum of values.  Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of ArcGIS in use and provide more details on what you have attempted. I'm changing the tags to reflect raster, not vector, operation.

Comment: Have a look at the local toolset in spatial analyst tool box, may be the [EqualtoFrequency](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/equal-to-frequency.htm) is what you need?

Comment: Cell statistics sum should do.